# How to create a rect from a size?

Tags: swift, cgrect

Ultimately, I'm trying to retrieve the contentSize of my dynamic UIScrollView.

I'm doing this with this loop :

```
    var contentRect = CGRectZero
    for view: UIView in self.scrollView.subviews {
        var size : CGSize = (view.text?.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)]))
        contentRect = CGRectUnion( contentRect, CGRectMake(size) )
    }
    scrollView.contentSize = contentRect
```

The body of the loop is syntactically incorrect though. This is because you can't make a `CGRectMake` with the variable `size`.

Would anyone know how I can properly create this shape? Is there a better way to refactor this code to make it more elegant?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add x and y coordinates for it to work. Should be something like this:

```
var contentRect = CGRectZero
for view: UIView in self.scrollView.subviews {
    var size : CGSize = (view.text?.sizeWithAttributes([NSFontAttributeName: UIFont.systemFontOfSize(14.0)]))
    let rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)
    contentRect = CGRectUnion( contentRect, rect )
}
scrollView.contentSize = contentRect
```

Comment: `CGRectMake(0, 0, size.width, size.height)`, really? I'd use `CGRect(origin: .zero, size: size)`

Comment: Yup that's probably even better!